# Need help on Tree Items Iteration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, automated-tests

I am using Q7 from Xored and pretty new to ECL. I need help on first getting tree items in list and then iterating over it to get text of every node.

I will appreciate if anyone can let me know how I can do it.

Regards,

Manan

Comment: What sort of tree? Is this a `SWT` `Tree`, a `JFace` `TreeViewer` or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Get the tree items with:

```
 TreeItem [] items = tree.getItems();
```

call `TreeItem.getText()` to get the item text.